# Calculate route for heavy truck

Tags: here-api

When I use heavy truck (limitedWeight > 18tons) options I can't get route for road. I don't see any restrictions for that road.

This is a sample link with heavy truck calculate route https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=49.624139,20.722449&waypoint1=49.623984,20.726724&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&alternatives=3&weightPerAxle=8t&limitedWeight=18t&height=4m&width=2.55m&length=18m&trailersCount=1

If I change limitedWeight (to e.g. 15t) then the route is calculated.

This is the exact setup:

- Start: 49.624139, 20.722449
- Destination: 49.623984, 20.726724
- Traffic is disabled for route calculation
- TrailersCount = set to 1
- Truck dimensions were tested both with very small values and with real values

It is a problem of HERE's data? or I will must change parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that an API will never have inconsistent data, and in fact you searched for the Fleet API with the intuition to place restrictions on your route. The problem you are experiencing is the following, "the maximum weight for circulation on this road has been carried out", that is, how will it return a result if you passed the correct restrictions to him? What you can do is put the alternative routes, this way it will return the second best result based on your restrictions.

NOTE: This was meant to be a comment, but I can't do it because of the reputation